# PDE's: Analysis without solving explicitly the equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have the following PDE'S
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,r)=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\big((r-1/2)u(t,r)\big)$$
with $u(0, r)=u_0(r)$ compact supported in the interval $[0,1]$ and such that $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$.

I know the solution explicitly, Through the characteristic method we know that
that $$u(t,r)=u_0\big((r-1/2)e^t+1/2\big)e^t$$.

I am wondering about the $\lim_{t\to +\infty}\int_0^1u(t,r)G(r) dr$, with $G\in C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ a test function.

Since I know the explicit solution it is easy to understand that 
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\int_0^1u(t,r)G(r) dr=G(1/2)$$.

My question is, could I deduce something about the asymptotic behaviour without knowning the explicit solution but just looking at the expression of the PDE?

Comment: I think you want $G(1/2) \int_{-\infty}^\infty u_0(s)\; ds$ rather than $G(1/2)$ on the right of your limit.

Comment: You are right, I have the following hypotesis: $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$. I added it in the question. Thank you!

Comment: One way to understand the result physically is to write it as $\dot{\rho} + \nabla(\rho v) = 0$ where the mass density $\rho = u$ and the velocity $v=1/2-r$. This is the well-known continuity equation for a fluid describing conservation of mass: $M = \int \rho\,{\rm d}r = 1$ is conserved in time. If you look at the velocity field, this is such that matter flows towards $r=1/2$ from both sides. As time goes on we therefore expect all the mass to pile up at this point ($u\to M\delta(r-1/2)$). The integral is the mass-weighted average value of $G$ which will therefore just be $G$ at $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

This is really closely related to the method of characteristics, but doesn't explicitly use the solution.

Consider $$J = J(a(t), b(t), t) = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} u(t,r)\; dr $$ 
where $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are continuously differentiable functions.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have
$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{dJ}{dt} &= b'(t) u(t,b(t)) - a'(t) u(t,a(t)) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,r) \; dr \cr
&= b'(t) u(t,b(t)) - a'(t) u(t,a(t)) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \left((r-1/2) u(t,r)\right)\; dr \cr
&= (b'(t) + b(t) - 1/2) u(t, b(t)) - (a'(t) + a(t) - 1/2) u(t, a(t))\cr} $$
In particular, this is $0$ if $b(t)$ and $a(t)$ are solutions of the differential equation $x' + x - 1/2 = 0$.  Those solutions all converge to $1/2$ as $t \to \infty$.  Thus if $[a(0), b(0)]$ contains the support of $u_0$, for large $t$
the support of $u(t,\cdot)$ is contained in the small interval $[a(t), b(t)]$ near
$1/2$, and $\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} u(t,r)\; dr = 1$. Take $\epsilon > 0$. If the interval is small enough that $|G(r) - G(1/2)|< \epsilon$,
we have

$$\left|\int_0^1 u(t,r) G(r)\; dr - G(1/2)\right| = \left|\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} u(t,r) (G(r) - G(1/2))\; dr \right| < \epsilon \int_{a(0)}^{b(0)} |u(t,r)|\; dr $$

Thus we get $$ \int_0^1 u(t,r) G(r)\; dr \to G(1/2)\ \text{as}\ t \to \infty$$